# What could be the reason why "heroku open" command is not working?

Tags: heroku

I have successfully deployed a django app on heroku using [this guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python?singlepage=true). The heroku cli is installed as a snap application on my system - I'm running Fedora 32 on a Dell xps 15 - and everything seems to be working fine except when I try to run the app locally.

When I attempt to run the app locally, I get the following error:

```
$ heroku open 

 ▸    Error opening web browser.

 ▸    Error: Exited with code 4
 ▸    
 ▸    Manually visit https://[myapp].herokuapp.com/ in your browser.
```

I tried variations of the command to no avail:

```
$ heroku open -a [myapp]
$ heroku open -r https://git.heroku.com/[myapp].git
```

When, instead, I run it with `heroku local` it runs without any problems.
I look at the logs but couldn't find any clues. Neither was I able to find any useful information.

What am I missing?

Comment: This isn't a problem with the `heroku` CLI, and `heroku local` has nothing to do with it. It just can't launch your browser. What browsers do you have installed?

Comment: I use primarily Firefox, but I have Chrome installed as well.

Comment: Just to clarify further, I also tried setting the browser as an environment variable like so: `BROWSER=firefox heroku open` and still got the same error!

Comment: "The heroku cli is installed as a snap application on my system"—this might be the issue. As far as I know, Snaps are isolated from the rest of your machine.

Comment: This was my suspicion as well. I will remove the snap installation and try one of the other recommended methods.

Comment: The issue appears not related to the installation. I did a fresh install using the official tarball and I am still experiencing the same behavior!
The only alternative I haven't tried is using npm because heroku explicitly discourages it.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the browser in your `~/.bashrc` using `export BROWSER=`

Answer (score 0):

If someone uses Windows Subsystem for Linux, set the `BROWSER` environment variable in the corresponding shell configuration file (e.g., `~/.zshrc`) to `wslview`.

```
export BROWSER=wslview
```